# Unable to use credentials to publish or install with yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm relatively recently researching npm and yarn for managing javascript packages.  For various reasons (mostly obvious to yarn users) I think I would like to settle on yarn long term.  For the past several days, while playing, after my first use of `yarn login`I have had no trouble using `yarn publish` and `yarn add` (or `yarn upgrade`) to publish and install private scoped modules through the npm registry.  Today, when starting to work on a full build package, used `yarn logout` to logout, and then tried logging in again with `yarn login`.  But now, I am completely unable to use `yarn publish` to publish my packages or `yarn install` to install any privately scoped packages.  npm works fine.

I'm baffled as to what has gone wrong.

Somehow the authentication is not working correctly and I don't see what I have done to break it.  That said, I don't understand it very well either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `npm login`. It will create a login token that is persistent, and `yarn` will also be able to use it.